# How can asymmetric intervals be generated by symmetric balls?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Following this post: [How can an interval be an open ball?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011071/how-can-an-interval-be-an-open-ball) There was an unresolved question in the comment

How can $(\alpha, \beta)$ be expressed in terms of open balls of the form $B(x, \epsilon) = (x - \epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, when the balls are symmetric and the intervals are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like that :

$$]\alpha, \beta[ = \left] \frac{\beta + \alpha}{2} - \frac{\beta - \alpha}{2}, \frac{\beta + \alpha}{2} + \frac{\beta - \alpha}{2} \right[ =  B(\frac{\beta + \alpha}{2} , \frac{\beta - \alpha}{2} )$$

ie. $x$ is the middle of $]\alpha, \beta[$